# Why does the DateTime not convert to the specified TimeZone?

Tags: c#, mysql, date, datetime, timezone

I have a mysql database that a user can add appointment records to, and I want to have functionality that automatically changes the DateTime value for appointments based on the timezone of the user's computer. For some reason I cannot get this to work.

I have tried existing solutions but maybe I'm missing something? Anytime date info is sent to the database I convert time to UTC:

```
private void UpdateAppointment()
{
    using (ent = new ScheduleEntities())
    {
        var currentAppointment = ent.appointments.Attach(AppointmentIndex);

        currentAppointment.start = start_TimePicker.Value.ToUniversalTime();
        currentAppointment.end = end_TimePicker.Value.ToUniversalTime();

        ent.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Then I convert to local time zone before adding records to a List:

```
private void ChangeTimeZone()
{
    Debug.WriteLine($"{TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.StandardName}");

    foreach (var item in userAppointments)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"before: {item.start} - {item.end}");

        item.start = DateTime.SpecifyKind(item.start, DateTimeKind.Local);
        item.end = DateTime.SpecifyKind(item.start, DateTimeKind.Local);

        item.start = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId(item.start, TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.StandardName);
        item.end = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId(item.end, TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.StandardName);

        Debug.WriteLine($"after: {item.start} - {item.end}");
    }
}

private void PopulateAppointmentGrid()
{
    if (all_Radio.Checked)
    {
        ChangeTimeZone();
        var allQuery = ent.appointments.Where(ap => ap.userId == ActiveUser.userId);

        ForEachListItem(allQuery, ap => userAppointments.Add(ap));
    }
}
```

Debug.WriteLine results:

> - TimeZone (I manually set from Eastern to Central, it recognizes the change)
> - before: 8AM
> - after: 8AM

Full code can be found here:

https://github.com/AustinSB/SchedulingApplication

Comment: Datetime will use the timezone from the server, if you dont change it for the connection. So as long as your data is viewed on from one timezone, calclaute the timezone difference and add or subtract the time.

Comment: Have you considered `DateTimeOffset` or NodaTime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things:

- You are correctly converting from local time to UTC using `.ToUniversalTime()`.  This works because when the `Kind` is `Unspecified`, then it is treated as local.  Thus, you are getting UTC values saved to your database.
- You're incorrectly asserting that the values being retrieved from your database are in local time.  Instead, assert that they are UTC with `SpecifyKind`, then convert to local time using `ToLocalTime`.

  Additionally, to make this operation idempotent, I recommend checking for `Unspecified` kind before doing any conversion.  That will prevent double-conversion if you call your method multiple times.

  ```cs
  if (item.start.Kind == DateTimeKind.Unspecified)
  {
      item.start = DateTime.SpecifyKind(item.start, DateTimeKind.Utc).ToLocalTime();
  }

  if (item.end.Kind == DateTimeKind.Unspecified)
  {
      item.end = DateTime.SpecifyKind(item.end, DateTimeKind.Utc).ToLocalTime();
  }
  ```
- Since you are only working between local time and UTC, you don't need to get the system's current time zone or time zone identifier, nor do you need to involve conversion functions from the `TimeZone` or `TimeZoneInfo` class.  (This advice only applies because this is a Windows Forms desktop application.  It would not apply to web applications, as there the *server's* local time zone controls the local time.)
- Don't use the `TimeZone` class at all.  Ever.  The reasons are numerous, and stated [in the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.timezone).  Specifically, in this case, note that `TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.StandardName` returns a localized string that will change based on the locale, and does not always align with the ID - even in English.

Comment: Thank you, I was able to resolve the issue with this solution.

Answer (score 1):

The `DateTime` objects are coming back from MySQL as `DateTimeKind.Unspecified`. When you execute this code, it forces them to be considered as being in local time, but doesn't change the actual time value:

```cs
item.start = DateTime.SpecifyKind(item.start, DateTimeKind.Local);
item.end = DateTime.SpecifyKind(item.start, DateTimeKind.Local);
```

This seems incorrect, because you saved the UTC value: `currentAppointment.start = start_TimePicker.Value.ToUniversalTime();`

Your time zone conversion very likely does nothing, because they're already in local time.

You could try `DateTime.SpecifyKind(item.start, DateTimeKind.Universal);` but you're likely to run into a different set of bugs if you ever use more than one timezone.

Consider storing full `DateTimeOffset` values as described in this article: https://mysqlconnector.net/troubleshooting/datetime-storage/.